# What is happening when we over write a existing file?

Tags: c#

I'm interesting in knowing what happens when I overwrite a file in .NET. I'm using C#.NET and here is an example of overwriting a file:

```
byte[] data = //some data bytes;
FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Assuming the variable `path` already contains a file called myfile.bin with some data and I want to over write this file with `dat`, my questions are:

1) What is the physical location in which the new data is going to written? (Written in a new location or an overwrite on the same location in which the earlier data existed)

2) Is it possible to recover the earlier data if it is over written in the same location?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C#.  It is an OS File I/O question and is a function of the underlying OS API and file system.

Answer (score 0):

It could be written anywhere and there is absolutely no gautantee that it will be in the same location. As to whether previously overwritten data can be recovered, it completely depends on the technology and the person/organization doing the recovery. At a minimum, you should never assume that data written to disk can *not* be recovered.